# How to Zoom camera while Video recording in ios 5

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, zooming

I am using AV Foundation for accessing Camera Features in iOS 5.I want to implement zooming functionality while video recording.But after going a lot of search I could not find a way.I can see the native camera of the iPhone also doesn't support video zooming.
But in some applications like "ProCamera","Luma" I found zooming while video recording.So,Please give me any suggestion to get video recording zoom feature in my app.Thanks.

Comment: This effect is most likely just zooming the view itself using a scroll view. You probably have many examples from apple on how to zoom and pan an image, you may copy the same example and modify it to swap images received from camera.

Comment: Matic,I want the output video file also be zoomed in/out according to the video's zooming.

Comment: You need to resample the received sample buffer for that, which can again be done by scroll view. Actually all you need is to create an image from layer and send it to recorder.

Comment: Matic,I have tried your suggestions but it doesnt work.Can you pleaswe provide any sample code.Thanks.